# React Native + Redux: How to render <ListView/> upon clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have two components: `AddingAnimalPanel.js` and `AnimalList.js`. I was trying trying to do the following:

In the `AddingAnimalPanel.js`, I have a button where once it is clicked, it calls a function `_addAnimal()` and that updates the state via redux, and the updated state gets passed into `AnimalList.js` and list the state via `<ListView/>`.

But I am getting an error: `Cannot read property 'rowIdentities' of undefined` and I didn't define initial state for the `animalData`. So I tried defining the initial state property `animalData` as an array, yet I still got an error: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. What am I doing incorrectly?

**Here is my code:**

In `AddingAnimalPanel.js`:

```
  _addAnimal() {
    var animals = [{animal: 'bird'}, {animal: 'cat'}, {animal: 'dog'}]

    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    var animalData = ds.cloneWithRows(animals)

    this.props.uploadAnimalData(animalData) //Calling action creator
  }
```

In action creators:

```
export const uploadAnimalData = (animalData) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.UPLOAD_ANIMAL_DATA,
    animalData: animalData,
  }
}
```

And in reducer:

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
 //Tried also both animalData:[] and animalData:{} but still got the length error
}

export default function(state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case actionTypes.UPLOAD_ANIMAL_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        animalData: action.animalData
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

And redux works correctly and props get passed down to `AnimalList.js`:

```
  _renderRow(rowData){
    return (
      <AnimalListRow rowData={rowData} {...this.props}/>
    )
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.props.animalData} //ListView is causing the error
          renderRow={this._renderRow}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

**EDIT - ADDITIONAL CODE**

This is my current set up for redux.

Reducer:

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {

}

export default function(state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case actionTypes.UPLOAD_ANIMAL_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        animalData: action.animalData
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const getAnimalData = (state) => ({
  animalData: state.animalData,
})
```

Using `connect` from react-redux inside a separate file called `index.js`, this is how `animalData` is being passed into `AnimalList.js` :

```
// @flow
import AnimalList from './AnimalList'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from './actions'
import {
  getAnimalData,
} from '../../reducers/rootReducer'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  ...getAnimalData(state),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(AnimalList)
```

Comment: I'm quite new to react, redux. But when I want to dispatch an action creator from my component, I connect my component with mapDispatchToProps function to redux state.`function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {


  return {
    animalData: animalData
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(uploadAnimalData, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddingAnimalPanel);`

Comment: @BadChanneler Appreciate you for responding but do you mind putting it as an answer? Fairly hard to make out what you suggested.

Comment: While debugging did you check the props variable? seems like you aren't passing the animalData prop in the redux connect with the getAnimalData method. Also in the reducer I would use `Object.assign({}, state... ` to merge the state and animalData property.

Answer (score 10):

I think you're on the right track, it is most likely a problem with the initial data. It's fairly difficult to pinpoint the exact problem without having an executable example though.

Supplying `ListView` with any object or array will not work. You have to provide the result of `ds.cloneWithRows()` or `ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections()` to the `ListView` component.

There are several courses of action that could be taken. What I would recommend, is moving the `Listview.DataSource`-functionality closer to where it is consumed, i.e. the `AnimalList` component. What you would initially store in the Redux store could then be an empty array. With `connect` from [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux), the gist of `AnimalList.js` could be:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


    ...


    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.props.animalData} //ListView isn't causing an error
            renderRow={this._renderRow}
          />
        </View>
      );
   }
}

const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
  rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    animalData: ds.cloneWithRows(state.animalReducer.animalData)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AnimalList);
```

Another way to accomplish the same result is to delay rendering of the `ListView` component and hold off `DataSource` creation until animalData is available. For example `AnimalList.js`:

```
  static propTypes = {
    animalData: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };      

  ...

  render() {
    let animalListView = this.props.animalData.length >= 1
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.animalData)}
        renderRow={this._renderRow}
      /> :
      null;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {animalListView}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT**: I noticed a couple more potential problems with your code.

For state changes to be propagated to reducers, you need to call `dispatch` from Redux. What you probably want to do in `AddingAnimalPanel.js`:

```
_addAnimal() {
  const { store } = this.context; // Assuming you're passing down a reference to store in context
  var animals = [{animal: 'bird'}, {animal: 'cat'}, {animal: 'dog'}]

  store.dispatch(this.props.uploadAnimalData(animals))
}
```

Check that `case actionTypes.UPLOAD_ANIMAL_DATA` in the reducer gets triggered as a result of this.

With the additional code you posted, if I managed to correctly mentally picture you code in action, `AnimalList.js`:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.props.animalData} //ListView isn't causing an error
          renderRow={this._renderRow}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
  rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  animalData: ds.cloneWithRows(...getAnimalData(state)),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(AnimalList)
```

What I then would do, is set

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  animalData: []
}
```

in your reducer. This way `state.animalData` is always a regular array and the `AnimalList` component handles the data conversion to the format `ListView` expects to receive the data.

If the setup is still unclear, try looking for an example app on e.g. GitHub and browse that code to get an idea of how it's all wired together.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I updated the original code with additional code for further clarification. Can't seem to wrap my head around how it would work with my current redux set up. Before I accept the answer and upvote, could you show the first suggestion with my additional code? Also do you recommend the first suggestion over the second? Trying to learn the best practice. Thank you NiFi

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try and let me know. First, put back the initial state in your reducer like you had it:

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
 animalData:[] 
}
```

Then, in the reducer try the following instead:

```
case actionTypes.UPLOAD_ANIMAL_DATA:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    animalData: action.animalData,
  })
```

Finally, in the `mapStateToProps` access the list using `state.animalData`. This last part might not be needed, I'm just not sure how your `getAnimalData` is used.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The reducer is perfectly fine as is, `...state` effectively produces the same result as `Object.assign`. Even found an [example demonstrating this in Redux's documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html).